# How to do a "many-to-one" join

Tags: qgis, postgresql, attribute-joins

I have used the distance matrix tool for a large point set (100 000+ points) to find three closest POI's from another layer and their distances. The distance matrix outputs a table much like this:

```
source   target_id   distance  
1        2          100
1        3          110
1        4          120 
2        1          100
2        3          200
2        4          210
```

My point layer is now even bigger because each original point has three separate features which only difference is the target_id and the distance from source to target. I would like to have the target_id and the distance in separate fields in one feature per source_id.

```
source   target_1   distance_1   target_2   distance_2   target_3   distance_3   
1        2          100          3          110          4          120
2        1          100          3          200          4          210
...
```

I have tried all the basic tools I can use in QGIS without any luck. Seems like I am trying to do a "many-to-one" join, which can not be made with join-by-attribute. Merging or dissolving the layer to itself doesn't help either. I suspect this could be a simple SQL join operation but I have no idea how I could perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PostgreSQL is an option for you, it can work this way.

Creating the table with dummy data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distance_matrix_output;
CREATE TABLE distance_matrix_output(
   source INTEGER NOT NULL ,
   target INTEGER NOT NULL,
   distance INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO distance_matrix_output(source, target, distance)
VALUES  (1,2,100),
        (1,3,110),
        (1,4,120),
        (2,1,100),
        (2,3,200),
        (2,4,210);
```

Creating the empty table with the transformed layout described above.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS distance_matrix_transformed;
CREATE TABLE distance_matrix_transformed(
   source INTEGER NOT NULL,
   target_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   distance_1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   target_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   distance_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   target_3 INTEGER NOT NULL,
   distance_3 INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

What you want to achieve is to first group the values together given the source id which you can achieve using `string_agg` and `GROUP BY 1`. Afterwards you use `regexp_split_to_array` to cast this concatenated string into an array of values. This array then can be used to insert into your expected table.

```sql
INSERT INTO distance_matrix_transformed(
    source, 
    target_1,
    distance_1, 
    target_2, 
    distance_2, 
    target_3, 
    distance_3)
SELECT 
    sg.source, 
    sg.target_agg[1]::INTEGER, 
    sg.distance_agg[1]::INTEGER, 
    sg.target_agg[2]::INTEGER, 
    sg.distance_agg[2]::INTEGER, 
    sg.target_agg[3]::INTEGER, 
    sg.distance_agg[3]::INTEGER 
FROM (
    SELECT  
        source, 
        regexp_split_to_array(string_agg(target::TEXT, ', '), ', ') AS target_agg, 
        regexp_split_to_array(string_agg(distance::TEXT, ', '), ', ') AS distance_agg
    FROM distance_matrix_output
    GROUP BY 1
) AS sg;
```

Which will give you (`SELECT * FROM distance_matrix_transformed`) :

```sql
source  | target_1 | distance_1 | target_2 | distance_2 | target_3 | distance_3
--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------
      2 |        1 |        100 |        3 |        200 |        4 |        210
      1 |        2 |        100 |        3 |        110 |        4 |        120
```

Comment: This seemed to work exactly as intended.

Comment: Glad to hear @Tom - please accept the answer if you can.